# How to authenticate to ODK aggregate using python

Tags: python, odk

I am building a python application and I need to be able to authenticate through an ODK aggregate server. By "authenticate" I mean that,  I need to send the login information (username and password) to the ODK aggregate server and it should return if the credentials are correct and the user is active.
I rather user python's requests library, but I am open to other suggestions.

Comment: seems like this is covered in their docs https://odkcentral.docs.apiary.io/#reference/authentication/session-authentication/logging-in  you probably want the "Basic" version

Comment: Thank you, but that documentations covers ODK central. My project needs to use ODK aggregate, wich is the old version.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://docs.getodk.org/openrosa-authentication/

P.S. As you'll likely already know ODK Aggregate reached end-of-life a couple of years ago, and has security issues (that won't be fixed).